# TemplateDoesNotExist at /hello/vscode following Django tutorial documentation

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, django-templates

Following the Django tutorial at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django but got an error of TemplateDoesNotExist at /hello/vscode.

The error is

```
hello/hello_there.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/vscode
Django Version: 2.2
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
hello/hello_there.html
Exception Location: C:\Users\v770704\Documents\hello_django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in get_template, line 19
Python Executable:  C:\Users\v770704\Documents\hello_django\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\v770704\\Documents\\hello_django',
 'c:\\Users\\v770704\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.python-2019.3.6215\\pythonFiles',
 'C:\\Users\\v770704\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\v770704\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\v770704\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\v770704\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32',
 'C:\\Users\\v770704\\Documents\\hello_django\\env',
 'C:\\Users\\v770704\\Documents\\hello_django\\env\\lib\\site-packages']
```

This is a path issue because the path to hello/templates/hello/hello_there.html is not found, but that path and file do exist.

Settings.py has an empty DIRS value, which is what I'm told to use for the DIRS in the tutorial.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

The Template-loader postmortem says:

```
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\v770704\Documents\hello_django\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\hello\hello_there.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\v770704\Documents\hello_django\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\hello\hello_there.html (Source does not exist)
```

If I copy the hello/templates/hello folder to the path it's looking in,

```
C:\Users\v770704\Documents\hello_django\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates,
```

the web page works correctly, so it appears to only be a path-configuration  issue.

I tried this from another post but get the same error:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
```

Even entering the full, literal path to the directory does not work.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you added 'hello' to `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yes, I had added 'hello', per the tutorial.

Comment: That's not possible. Either 'hello' isn't added to `INSTALLED_APPS` or you don't have a *templates* directory inside your hello app. I can tell that from the fact it only looked in `auth` and in `admin` *templates* directories. Check that you have the following structure: *path/to/project/manage.py* and at the same level: *path/to/project/hello/templates/hello/<any_template>.html* (your *hello* app) and also at the same level *path/to/project/hello_django/settings.py* (the django project directory)

Comment: All files are in the correct places - but you helped me realize I had added "hello" to the settings.py in the web project instead of at the settings.py project-level file.  Problem solved.

Comment: @dirkgroten Sorry, I don't see a checkmark to click to accept your answer, and I am logged in.

Comment: no worries, it was a comment, not an answer.